# PHP mysqli issue with duplicate records

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having some issues when attempting to download the data from my MySQL database to my PHP code. Namely that I'm trying to insert multiple rows of data into one array. (This shouldn't be a difficult task)

I've gotten to the point where it picks up all of the rows from my database BUT not all of my rows have their ID numbers incrementally (For example, I have ID 1 and ID 5, since I've been removing some ID's and the count continues to increment regardless)

I would like to know how I could go about removing the duplicate rows between 1 and 5; (so that's 2, 3 and 4) and all rows after 5 until my next row that has unique data.

Here's what I've got so far:

**Get SQL Data**

```
public function do_retrieve_stored_message_data()
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","coursework_db");

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 999; $i = $i + 1)
    {
        $m_id_checker = $i;

        $SQL="SELECT message_id, message_date, message_time, message_last_value FROM cw_messages WHERE message_id = '" . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $m_id_checker) . "'";

        $resulting = mysqli_query($con, $SQL);

        while($db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulting))
        {
            $m_message_id = $db_field['message_id'];
            $m_message_date = $db_field['message_date'];
            $m_message_time = $db_field['message_time'];
            $m_message_last_value = $db_field['message_last_value'];
        }

        $m_arr_sql_query_parameters_1 = array($m_message_date, $m_message_time, $m_message_last_value);
        $m_arr_sql_query_parameters_2 = array_merge($m_arr_sql_query_parameters_1);
        $m_arr_sql_query_parameters = array_unique($m_arr_sql_query_parameters_2);

        foreach($m_arr_sql_query_parameters as $m_data)
        {
            echo "$m_data";
        }
    }

    $this->c_arr_stored_message_data['message-name'] = $m_message_id;
    $this->c_arr_stored_message_data['message-retrieved-data'] = $m_arr_sql_query_parameters;
```

**Example Input**

> 1.2014-08-02.11:43:33.11345446 (Full-stops indicate different columns from the database, but aren't in the actual example)
>
> 5.2014-08-05.11:48:33.11342249

**Expected Output**

```
foreach($m_arr_sql_query_parameters as $m_data)
{
  echo "$m_data";
}

Output: 2014-08-02.11:43:33.11345446.2014-08-05.11:48:33.11342249
```

(Again, the full-stops are only there to serve as markers and won't be there in the real code)

Post-Script: The data echoed in "$m_data" repeats itself 999 times, as you would expect inside a for loop, so I know it picks up the IDs; but outside the for loop, it only picks up the last data entry in my database and not any of the others.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the variables you assign inside your `while` loop. Just overwriting them each iteration.

Comment: @ccKep The `while` loop or the `for` loop? because the `while` loop is inside the `for` loop, it doesn't need to be assigned, because the next line after the `while` loop deals with that

Comment: You are overwriting your variables `$m_message_id`,`$m_message_date`,`$m_message_time` and `$m_message_last_value` everytime in the while loop. For everything after the while loop (including your `array_merge`/`array_unique` stuff) those variables just contain their values from the last iteration (eg. your last row).

Comment: @ccKep I want to overwrite those variables, as I want to save the new variables in the merged array with the old ones.

Comment: I think you should step through your code line by line. It doesn't do what you think it does. In order to help you it'd be best if you could post input examples and **your expected output**. Your `array_merge` call doesn't even do **anything** since you only give it one array. Your `array_unique` call doesn't do what you intend since it doesn't operate on the array keys (which you didn't assign anyway).

Comment: @ccKep Alright, I'll get on that. I thought array_merge would work with just one array. It seemed to on the php help website.

Comment: `array_merge` takes any number of arrays and merges them together, returning the merged array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59212/discussion-between-raisus-and-cckep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after your comments the intended goal isn't clear to me.

However, I'll leave you with this snippet that fetches all your data and saves it into an array - maybe this will help you along.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","coursework_db");

    $sql = "SELECT message_id, message_date, message_time, message_last_value FROM cw_message WHERE message_id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $m_id_checker) . "'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    // Actual Snippet begins here
    $rows = array();
    while (($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)))
    {
        $rows[] = array(
            "id" => $data["message_id"],
            "date" => $data["message_date"],
            "time" => $data["message_time"],
            "last_value" => $data["message_last_value"],
        );
    }
    // Snippet to get all data into an array ends here

    // Printing the returned data
    print_r($rows);
?>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This works. I even got rid of the horrid `for` loop :D